# jqgrid delete all rows inside grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way to delete all rows in one function call? and not by looping through all rows and deleting row by row.

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's depend on what you exactly mean under "deleting of all rows". The method [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#add_on_grid_methods) could be very helpful in many cases, but it delete more as only grid contain.

Another method used intern in jqGrid is:

```
var trf = $("#list tbody:first tr:first")[0];
$("#list tbody:first").empty().append(trf);
```

Probably it is what you need. It delete all grid rows excepting of the first one. You can overwrite the code also as the following

```
var myGrid = $("#list"); // the variable you probably have already somewhere
var gridBody = myGrid.children("tbody");
var firstRow = gridBody.children("tr.jqgfirstrow");
gridBody.empty().append(firstRow);
```

Answer (score 41):

If you mean remove all rows from the grid you can just do this..

```
$('#grid1').jqGrid('clearGridData');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to remove all rows and insert grid data back, you may use `$('#grid1').jqGrid('GridUnload');` 
Otherwise, you can use [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920323/jqgrid-gridunload-griddestroy) suggested by Oleg