# jqGrid empty and redisplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to remove jqGrid and reDisplay it with another data.
is it correct to follow this:

```
 $("div#disp").empty().append("<table id='display'>");
 $("table#display").jqGrid({...});
```

when `div#disp` surronds `table#display`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you need. The best way is depend on the exact requirements.

If you just want to change the grid contain without adding or removing a grid column you can just change some grid parameters, `postData` and probably `url` and then call `$('#list').trigger('reloadGrid')`.

If you need to show really another grid on the same place the usage of `GridUnload` method can solve the problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) for more information and the demo.

If you need some optimization in removing of grid contain you can do what described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818319/jqgrid-delete-all-rows-inside-grid/5818577#5818577).

[jqgrid delete all rows inside grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818319/jqgrid-delete-all-rows-inside-grid/5818577#5818577)

Comment: I need to add columns in dynamic way, this is the best I've got thanks for pointing to the custom methods

Comment: @shevski: If you add column dynamically you should know one more way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383847/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-colmodel-after-data-has-loaded-with-jqgrid/5408195#5408195).