# JQGrid and asp.net

Tags: c#, jqgrid

In the past when I've used jqgrid all i have done is had a static web service and the grid loads as the page does. Now I need to have a form that i want to send values from to the service, and the results need to be in the grid.

I'm struggling with a couple of things -

- How do i format the url function in the grid to send parameters with it, in the past i have got away with just `url: 'JsonData.asmx/GetData`
- How do i actually call the update method of the grid from a button?

I'm writing the web app in c#, dotnet 4

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem in what you explain. If you could fill the grid data using `url: 'JsonData.asmx/GetData'` it should continue to work inside of the form. You should only verify the font size which you use in the form to have good look together with the grid.

If you need reload data in the grid you can use `$("#grid_id").trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014)).

One other possible problem which you could have: one should create jqGrid once. If you for example need create the form once which contain one grid and later change the for contain to have another grid you could have to use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920323/jqgrid-gridunload-griddestroy/4920612#4920612).