# jqGrid - Removing all rows without calling loadComplete or gridComplete

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to remove all rows of jqGrid be removed without calling gridComplete event.

Comment: removing?? what do u mean? explain?

Comment: removing means clearing the grid without calling gridComplete

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of methods that you can use. gridDestroy and grid Unload, you can use any of them based on your requirement.

Check this link for further refrence [jqGrid GridUnload/ GridDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920323/jqgrid-gridunload-griddestroy)

or you can use this

$('#grid1').jqGrid('clearGridData');