# jqGrid local data within ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Hello stackoverflow nation !
I've such a snag. Trying to pass in jqGrid array data which is retrieved within ajax, but it doesn't work. lets take a look at script =>

```
$(function(){ // this script works just fine (of course this array and jqGrid initialization script is in the same file)
var arr = [
    {a:"a",b:"b"},
    {a:"c",b:"d"}
];
$("#_tb").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: arr,
    colNames: ["ONE","Two"],
    colModel: [
        {name:"a",index:"a",align:"center"},
    {name:"b",index:"b",align:"center"}
    ],
    pager: $("#_pager"),
    height: "auto"
});
});
```

here is my problem =>

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../info.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {},
    success: function(r){
        $("#_tb").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: r,
        colNames: ["ONE","Two"],
        colModel: [
            {name:"a",index:"a",align:"center"},
            {name:"b",index:"b",align:"center"}
        ],
        pager: $("#_pager"),
        height: "auto"
        });
    }
    });
```

this script doesn't work , but data is successfully retrieved within ajax into json format.
here is `info.php` script by the way too

```
// using PDO for connection
foreach($con->query("SELECT * FROM tb") as $row){
    $info[] = array(
        "a" => $row["a"],
        "b" => $row["b"]
    );
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

PS. In my opinion my problem is connected to **datatype** , but can't made up my mind how to solve that despite of searching examples like that . 
Also remarkable is that I want datatype to be local , because of searching and filtering data in jqGrid without any SQL where statements.
With any advice I'll be pleased , thanks :)

Comment: If you want to use your current code you should probably add additional parameters of `jQuery.ajax` like `dataType: "json"` or `contentType: "application/json"`. If you will use wrong parameters the type of `r` parameter in the `success` callback could be `string` instead of array of objects. So could could be require to convert `r` to object manually by call of `$.parseJSON(r)`.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for advices. So in second example where I'm trying to retrieve information from server and add in into jqGrid as a local it is possible if I'll convert it yes :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but the code which you posted do work: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Tornike.htm):

[image]

So you should search for the problem in another place.

One possible problem for example could be that you execute the code *multiple times*. You should create grid *once* and then change the data by changing the value of `data` parameter and trigger `reloadGrid`. By the way you can use `url: "../info.php"` directly in the jqGrid. You need just add the corresponding `jsonReader` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)). To be able to use local filtering you need just add `loadonce: true` to the list of jqGrid parameters. Alternatively you can call `GridUnload` method every time *before* recreating the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935) for exmaple).