# How to Destroy jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQgrid with multiple columns, when I press Clear button on my page, it is supposed to destroy the grid and everything that binds to the grid along. I know about the method gridDestroy and unload, but it is not working for me...any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should use `GridUnload` instead of `GridDestroy` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935) for more details). The only what you will need to do is to resave the value of jQuery variables if any used before. For example if you have table with id="list" and you saved `$("#list")` *before* calling of `GridUnload` in a variable (like `var myGrid=$("#list");`) then you should reassign the value of `$("#list")` to the same variable (execute `myGrid=$("#list");` one more time after the call of `GridUnload`).