# jqGrid reloadGrid and refresh new colModel and colNames

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to reload a jqGrid with new rows, colNames and colModel. The row data seems to load fine but the columns don't seem to be refreshed. I've tried using GridUnload and GridDestroy but I end up losing the jQuery DOM instance entirely and no longer loads any data as well.

```
var grid = $('#my-grid');

if(grid[0].grid == undefined) {
    grid.jqGrid(options);
} else {
    grid.setGridParam(options);
    grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

The grid instance is important because it will be passed to other objects as a param. These objects may attach listeners or trigger events.

I'm using version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that jqGrid removes the initial `<table></table>` from the DOM and replaces it or forgets the reference (I haven't looked that hard into it).

So you have to reselect the new table everytime you want to create a new grid ie. `$('table#my-grid')`. This makes it tricky if you want to pass a reference of the grid's table about to other parts of your app as a parameter.

My work around involves deleting the grid reference and replacing the grid's wrapped div with the original table. then creating a jqGrid in the normal way with the new colModel and colNames.

```
grid.empty();
delete grid[0].grid;
$('#gbox_my-grid').replaceWith(grid);
grid.jqGrid(options);
```

It isn't the tidiest of solutions but it does allow me to keep a permanent reference to the original `<table>`. I'm uncertain how other jqGrid plugins will be affect by this though.

Edit

it turns out [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) is better suited for customisation and we have adopted this instead of using jqGrid.

Comment: #JS
var grid = $('#jqGrid');
  if(grid[0].grid == undefined) {
     grid.jqGrid(options);
   } else {
    grid.empty();
    delete grid[0].grid;
    $('#gbox_jqGrid').replaceWith(grid);
    grid.jqGrid(options);
   }
#HTML
<table id="jqGrid"></table>

Answer (score 7):

`reloadGrid` reload only the *body* of the grid and not changes the column headers which will be created when the grid was created.

If you need to change number of columns or to use `colNames` and `colModel` on place of old grid you have or *recreate* grid. You can use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method first and then create new grid (call `grid.jqGrid(data)` in your case). It's important that if you cached jQuery selector to grid in a variable like `grid` in your code you have to assign `grid` one more time after call of `GridUnload`, so you should do something like `grid = $("#grid");` directly after call of `GridUnload`.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935) for more details and the code example.

Comment: as mentioned using GridUnload() before using jqGrid() didn't work and when tried a second type it throws `TypeError: d.emptyRows is null` in jquery

Comment: @gawpertron: I suppose that you use it in a wrong way. You can verify that the demo from the referenced answer do work without any problems in jqGrid 4.4.2 or 4.4.4. I suppose that you do'n reassign value of `grid` after usage of `GridUnload` like I described in my answer. If you have problems you should *append your question with the **current** code which you use*.

Comment: yes your answer will work in most cases. but I have a special case where I need to keep the reference to the original table element intact

Comment: @gawpertron: I don't understand the reason *why* you need to have *the same* DOM element of `<table>`. The only reason could be that you hold the reference to the element in a variable. So like I wrote you should just assign to the variable new value. The problem that jqGrid build dynamically *a lot of* other DOM elements inside the `<table>` and many divs over it. `<table>` only 1) defines the place of grid and the name of id used as prefix/suffix in other elements of grid. Why it could be needed to hold unchanged exactly the `<table>` if all other elements over the `<table>` will be changed?

Answer (score 2):

I have combined both answers and made some modification in order to have it to work.

```
var grid = $('#tableID');

if(grid[0].grid == undefined) {
  grid.jqGrid(options);
} else {
  delete grid;
  $('#tableID').GridUnload('#tableID');
  $('#tableID').jqGrid(options);
}
```