# How to show jqgrid data dynamically using entityframwork with sql data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, jqgrid

hi bosses i have used sql pivot to show employeewise product in grids. when i execute the query in management studio it is working fine but the problem is when i want to show data in jqgrid in with dynamic rows and columns it is not working. I am new in jqgrid.

here is my controller action method

```
public ActionResult FindOrderByEmployeeCall() 
        {
            var query = (from fo in db1.FindOrderByEmp1()
                         select fo).ToList();
            return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

my ajax method for show data in jqgrid in view page is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Invoice/FindOrderByEmployeeCall/",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                var colD = result.couponStripList,
                    colM = result.colModelList;

                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    //datatype: 'local',
                    data: "",
                    gridview: true,
                    colModel :colM,
                    height: "auto",
                    loadComplete: function(data){
                        alert('loaded');
                    },
                    loadError: function(xhr,status,error){
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(x, e){
                alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my sql pivot query is

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[FindOrderByEmp1]

as
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF;
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Product NVARCHAR(max),@Product1 NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT  @Product = STUFF(( SELECT distinct'],['+  rtrim(ProdId) FROM OrderDetails ORDER BY '],['+ rtrim(ProdId) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')+']'
set @Product1 =SUBSTRING(( select distinct ',IsNull(['+rtrim(ProdId)+'],0) as ['+rtrim(ProdId)+']' from OrderDetails for xml path('')),2,8000)

SET @query =
'SELECT EmpId,'+@Product1+'  FROM
(

    SELECT d.ProdId,m.EmpId,isnull(convert(int,d.Qty),0.0) as oqty
    FROM OrderMaster m inner join OrderDetails d on m.OrdId=d.OrdId
)t
PIVOT (SUM(oqty)
 FOR ProdId
IN ('+@Product+')) AS pvt' 
EXECUTE (@query)

end
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

JqGrid supports the pivot grid see below link

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pivotsettings

it loaded only once if you want to change the rows and column at runtime use GridUnload before creating and loading the grid.

[jqGrid GridUnload/ GridDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920323/jqgrid-gridunload-griddestroy)