# Reload jqGrid with new data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this simple function

```
function createGrid(limit){
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:indexObj.gridUrl,
        postData:{
            "limit":limit
        },
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['ID','type','folder','Description'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:50},
            {name:'type',index:'type', width:100},
            {name:'folder_id',index:'folder_id', width:100},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:200} 
        ]
    });
}
```

I first call it with limit = 1 and it calls the server and returns the right data.
Then I call it with limit = 2 and it just reruns the previous ajax call (with limit=1) and returns the same data of course.

Why **postData** doesn't actually change? I see in fireBug that "limit" does have the correct value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or while reloading you can use `setGridParam` for resetting `postData`,

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { 
        postData: {"limit":limit }
 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

And, you don't need to reinitialize/create jqGrid but you can simply use:

```
function createGrid(limit){
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
    #Code Goes here#
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that the construct with such caching of the data is good, but nevertheless your current problem is clear.

It's important to understand that the call

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url:indexObj.gridUrl,
    ...
});
```

**creates the grid**. It converts empty `<table id="list"></table>` in very complex structure of divs and tables. So **one can create the grid only once**.

The grid consist from many parts (like headers) which don't need be recreated on the next filling of the grid. So jqGrid provides `reloadGrid` event which can be triggered to *refill the body* of the grid. If jqGrid have `postData` with some value like

```
postData: {
    limit: limitVar
}
```

then if means that the object value of `postData` will be created and initialized **once** with the current value of `limitVar` variable. If you have **outer** variable (global, or defined in some outer scope) then you can use

```
postData: {
    limit: function () { return limitVar; }
}
```

In the case you will have *the current* value of `limitVar` as the value of `limit` parameter of URL. By the way if the user just click on the column header, the grid need be sorted and jqGrid will make new HTTP request to `url`. If you use `function` inside of `postData` then you will have *the current* value of `limitVar` in the cases too.

If you will make less modification in your existing code then you can replace the line `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");` (which is absolutely unneeded in the current code) to

```
$("#list").jqGrid("GridUnload");
```

It will destroy previously created structure of dives and tables (which build the grid) and creates an empty `<table id="list"></table>` on the same place. So you can recreate the grid. Such code will work not so effectively, but it could be very helpful in some scenarios (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232168/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935) for example).

Comment: Strangely, I get an "jqGrid - No such method: GridUnload" error in $("#list").jqGrid("GridUnload");

Comment: @CoffeeCode: You should verify jqGrid which you loaded. Probably you used **custom** download from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) and you didn't included the **custom** module (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.custom.js#L125))? I recommend you just include `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You can open the file in any text editor and search for `GridUnload`.