# Jquery grid loading only on 1st click and not reloading on subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax

I have a `JQuery` grid which is being populated on a button click based on certain drop-down selections.

The grid is loaded with data on the first button click. But on subsequent clicks the grid doesn't reload based on the changed drop-down selections.

The grid data loaded on the first button click persists until and unless i reload the page.

I have gone through some solutions online,such as

1. using `$("#tblJQGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");`for subsequent clicks except for the first click
2. `cache:false` property.

But none of them worked.

Here is my `jqgrid` code for reference

```
function BindGridData()
{
    $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid(
            {url: "@Url.Action("GetGeographyBreakUpData", "GeoMap")"+ "?Parameters=" + Params + "",
                datatype: "json",
                //data: { "Parameters": Params },
                async: false,
                mtype: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                colNames: ['Id','GeoGraphy', 'Completed', 'InProgress'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 20, stype: 'text',hidden:true },
                { name: 'Geography', index: 'Geography', width: 150 },
                { name: 'Completed', index: 'Completed', width: 150 },
                { name: 'InProgress', index: 'InProgress', width: 150 },
                ],
                pager:'#pager',
                jsonReader: {cell:""},
                rowNum: 10,
                sortorder: "desc",
                sortname: 'Id',
                viewrecords: true,

                caption: "Survey Status:Summary",
                scrollOffset: 0});

 }
```

And here is how  i am initialising the button click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var firstClick=true;
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            btnSubmitClick();
            debugger
            if(!firstClick)
            {
                $("#tblJQGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
            firstClick=false;
            BindGridData();
        });
});
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: This may be of help to you, a working sample http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are typical misunderstanding what the code `$("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid({...});` do. It's **create** the grid. It means that in converts the empty table `<table id="btnSubmit"></table>` in relatively complex structure of divs and tables. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). After understanding of that it should be clear that the second calling of `BindGridData` has no sence, becsue `table#btnSubmit` is not more empty. jqGrid tests it and just do nothing. Thus your current code just trigger `reloadGrid` with *the old* URL (see `Params`).

To fix the problem you have two main options:

1. usage `url: "@Url.Action("GetGeographyBreakUpData", "GeoMap")"` and `postData` with properties defined as **functions** (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935))
2. recreate the grid on click *instead of* triggering `reloadGrid`. You can call `GridUnload` method (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935)) before call of `BindGridData`.

Answer (score 0):

If the grid have data already, subsequent click on button or changing the drop down menu will not load new data on the grid. To resolve this problem, first unload the grid and load the new data again to grid.

**If button used, use the below code snippets**

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    $('#tblJQGrid').jqGrid('GridUnload');
    BindGridData();
  });
```

**Incase dropdown used, use the below code snippets,**

```
$("#btnSubmit").change(function(){
   $('#tblJQGrid').jqGrid('GridUnload');
   BindGridData();
  });
```