# Issue in Hiding JQGRID when No data Returned

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid

I was following this link to hide JQGRID when No Data Returned [How can I hide the jqgrid completely when no data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167477/how-can-i-hide-the-jqgrid-completely-when-no-data-returned/1167902#1167902)

Am using the below code in .cshtml

```
<div id="gridWrapper">
    <table id="list1">
    </table>
    <div id="pager">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="noSearchResults">
    No records Found!
</div>
```

and in GridComplete

```
gridComplete: function () {
    var recs = parseInt($("#list1").getGridParam("records"), 10);
    if (isNaN(recs) || recs == 0) {
        $("#gridWrapper").hide();
        $("#noSearchResults").Show();
    }
    else {
        $('#gridWrapper').show();
        $("#noSearchResults").Hide();
    }
}
```

But when $("#noSearchResults") is executed result is not as expected am getting Error catch in Jqgrid file. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Show will be "show" and Hide will be "hide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code except **Hide** should be **hide** and **Show** should be **show** change this, if you getting error then provide your grid definition.