# jqGrid how can I hide subgrid if it empty?

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

How can i hide a subgrid if it empty?
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167477/how-can-i-hide-the-jqgrid-completely-when-no-data-returned) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019155/how-to-display-information-in-jqgrid-that-there-are-not-any-data) but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538656/315935). It seems be exactly what you need.

Comment: There was nice solution, but isn't exactly what I need.  In my case i have rows which should be with subgrid, and should be without subgrid in one table. There are different between them only that in ones presents data in subgrid in other aren't. [Link](http://a-venu.com/?s=&vn_city=&vn_state=&vn_venue_type=&vn_room_setup_type=&vn_guest_rooms_required=&vn_max_mtg_occupanccy=&vn_largest_mtg_rooms=&vn_total_room_sq_ft=&vn_length_minimum_ft=&vn_width_minimum_ft=&vn_height_minimum_ft=) to demo if you scroll down you will see 4 rows which shouldn't be with subgrid

Comment: BTW, I take your solution for my work. Thanks. But still wait answer )

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019155/how-to-display-information-in-jqgrid-that-there-are-not-any-data) and Oleg's answer i resolve my problem.
In my table all rows are expanded so code looks like this for main table:

```
gridComplete: function(){
   var table_name = 'table_18';
   var myGrid = $('#'+table_name);
   var rowIds = myGrid.getDataIDs();
   $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId){
          myGrid.expandSubGridRow(rowId);
   });

   var subGridCells = $("td.sgexpanded",myGrid[0]);
   $.each(subGridCells,function(i,value){
          $(value).unbind('click').html('');
   });
}
```

In this code i removed click action for expand/collapse subgrids. So they are always open and there is no posibility to collapse them.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019155/how-to-display-information-in-jqgrid-that-there-are-not-any-data) i remove empty subgrids.

```
loadComplete: function(){//in subgrid 
        var table_value = $('#'+subgrid_table_id).getGridParam('records');
        if(table_value === 0){
            $('#'+subgrid_id).parent().parent().remove();
        }
}
```

Maybe exist more simple and elegant solution, but for me it's works as i expected.