# How to determine if JQGrid has value in first load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I found this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685823/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-jqgrid-has-data-or-not) and I try the answer but it is only counting the row not the data in jqgrid.

**Code**

```
function testingforBBPDS() {
    var BBPDSCount = jQuery('#BBDPSEmplList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
    if (BBPDSCount > 0) {
        $("#btnRemoveByBatchAllEmp").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

It return `5` not `2` because I have `2` data in my jqgrid at first load.

Answer (score 0):

TO all who view my post I solved it by using this `var test= jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');` and I put it inside the loadComplete function

Thanks for this [LINK](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/get-count-of-records-currently-in-jqgrid/)